# How to create installer setup for Windows phone Apps using visual studio ultimate 2010?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to create an installer for Windows Phone Apps i.e specific folder for images,specific folder for music. Audio file should be in music folder when app is installed in wp. Can anybody please provide an sample with screenshot???

Answer (score 0):

When you compile a Windows Phone 7 application an XAP file gets created in the Bin/Debug or Bin/Release folder depending on your configuration.

To install this pre-release application on other developers emulator or phone they need the Windows Phone SDK installed. Once installed open:

**Application Deployment**

- Select a device
- Point to the XAP location.

This will instal your application

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do anything like during the installation phase, as either the marketplace or the local xap takes care of it and you, as a developer do not have access to the folders were the apps are installed.

The best you can do is to create the required dirs in isolated storage the first time your app runs and copy anything either from the xap file, if the items are stored there, or copy them down from some sort of cloud storage possible,